# Listview in Fragment Using ArrayAdapter not setting up

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I want to setup Listview Using ArrayAdapter in Fragment.Here is my All Code.

Fragment :::

```
public class HairstylesFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView HairStylelz;
    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.man_menu_buzz,
            R.drawable.man_menu_buzz,
            R.drawable.man_menu_buzz,
            R.drawable.man_menu_buzz,
            R.drawable.man_menu_buzz,
            R.drawable.man_menu_buzz,
            R.drawable.man_menu_buzz
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hairstyles, container, false);
        HairStylelz=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.Listview_HairStyle);

        HairStylez_Adapter  adapter = new HairStylez_Adapter(view.getContext(),imageId);
        HairStylelz.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

ArrayAdapter::

```
public class HairStylez_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

     Integer[] imageId;
    Context context;



    public HairStylez_Adapter(Context context, Integer[] imageId) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_adapter_hairstyle);
        this.context=context;
        this.imageId=imageId;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_adapter_hairstyle, null, true);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Hairstyle_imageview);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

        Log.d("settingup","");
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

But Listview is Not Setting Up Its Showing Blank Screen.
is there Any Missing in my Code ?
Help to Setup Listview In Fragment

Thanks

Comment: i m not sure but to me it seems you require to use Baseadapter, as you are using ArrayAdapter<String> and you are passing Integer array. Try override getCount(), getItemId(int position) and getItem(int position) methods and return imageId count, 0 and imageId[position]. OR try changing ArrayAdapter<String> to ArrayAdapter<Integer>. Also try adding adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after you setAdapter

Comment: Thanks @RajenRaiyarela its Working You Saved My time. Just Add this In answer i will Give Right mark of this

Comment: Welcome. But m not sure which one of my suggestion worked as i gave you 2 - 3 suggestions to check.

Comment: I Just Use BaseAdapter Insted Of ArrayAdapter So Please Consider it in answer i will Give you Right Mark to your Answer @RajenRaiyarela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your use case i can suggest you to use BaseAdapter and override `getCount()`, `getItemId(int position)` and `getItem(int position)` methods and return  imageId.length, 0 and imageId[position]. Below is sample implementation of BaseAdapter.

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Integer[] imageId;
        Context context;
         
        public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, Integer[] imageId) {
            this.context=context;
            this.imageId=imageId;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_adapter_hairstyle, null, true);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Hairstyle_imageview);
            imageView.setImageResource(getItem(position));

            Log.d("settingup","");
            return rowView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {     
            return imageId.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer getItem(int position) {
            return imageId[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside getView() method :

```
if (view == null) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_adapter_hairstyle, parent, true);
}
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Hairstyle_imageview);
imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

Log.d("settingup","");
return view; //You are initialing view and returning rowView which is wrong.
```

You should inflate the view only once if it is null.And while inflating pass parent.

Comment: what is rowview ?? @Akshay Bhat

Comment: You are not update properly itr return view instead of rowview

Comment: Sorry, but pass parent while inflating. It will work. I updated

Comment: its Not Worinkig.i am Using Side Bar Menu.So is there Any diff Style to setup Listview in Fragment If yes than Give me Link for GiideThanks

Comment: Thanks For Help its Solve

Answer (score 1):

You need to add String data to ArrayAdapter by calling add(someValue)

Comment: i have to setup only image in listview